# iPad behavior when connected to MBP is confusing me - won't stay connected, repeatedly turns off after shut down

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, charging

I've recently experienced some issues when attempting to connect my iPad to my MBP to charge. It's possible that it's related to the cable I'm using but I find it extremely frustrating and I was hoping there was some solution or explanation for the behavior.

I have an iPad Pro 11 inch (3rd Gen) - I've not generally had issues plugging it into my MBP (2021 14 inch M1 running Ventura 13.6) but I've been driven somewhat batty recently because when I plug it in to charge (I'm not interested in data), the iPad won't stay connected if I'm using it while it's plugged in and if I'm not using it, the lock screen lights up every minute or two.

To attempt to just get it to stop the repetitive popups on my laptop ("a software update is required to connect to your iPad" and "allow accessory to connect") so that it would charge, I tried to turn it off using the Settings > General > Shut Down process. I did this at least three times and within a minute or two of shutting down, the iPad just turns on again without me touching it. This is *extremely* frustrating. If I were somewhere I could charge it without using my laptop, I would, but I'm not always able to do that and I'd just like to charge without being constantly interrupted by lit-up screens and pop-ups asking if I trust the computer every minute or two.

The cable works to charge the iPad with no issues in general. If it's plugged into a charging brick it does just fine and charges with no interruptions. It's a pretty standard USB C cable by Anker. I've tried swapping the ends of the cable, moving to different ports on the laptop, etc. I just don't understand why it won't connect and stay connected or why it keeps turning on if I shut it down entirely.

Is this *just* because I tell it "don't trust" and say not to connect to the laptop? If so, why would this be a *new* issue instead of something I've experienced before. The laptop used to belong to my workplace, so I didn't want it to connect data but I guess I can allow it now, I'm just very confused about this behavior.

Are there settings on my iPad or MBP that I can adjust to prevent this behavior?